# Is there a Rails way of making a form with a nested polymorphic relation (new or existing)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, polymorphism, nested-forms

I have a model `Navigation` that has a polymorphic `target`. That `target` can be a `Page`, an `ExternalLink`, or a `Plugin`. Each of these targets has different attributes (page has `content`, `title`, external link has `title`, `url`, plugin has its own polymorphic relations.

I'm building a little form to add a Navigation link, and I want to give my users the option to select an existing one of these relations (which is easy enough, just a grouped collection select), but I also would like to let them select a 'New' option for each of these `target` models.

The question is -- how do I include it in the same form?

I could make a form object, but that feels like the last-resort option. I know I can accept nested attributes for `target`, but I don't know how to do that with a selection form as well. I know I could do some js hackery to add or remove form elements on selecting or not selecting the 'new' options.

All of these don't feel railsey. This problem feels like a not-uncommon issue, and I imagine this is a solved problem that I'm trying to reinvent the wheel for. What option am I missing? What is the rails way to make this?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the [Cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), will handle a lot of the "js hackery" you alluded to.

[This post](http://www.powpark.com/blog/programming/2014/05/07/rails_nested_forms_for_single_table_inheritance_associations) shows how to use Cocoon to render the appropriate fields for (in your case) each of the possible `target` classes.

Whether you have a separate button for each target class is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `globalid` gem for this.

Here is a [good article](http://stefan.haflidason.com/simpler-polymorphic-selects-in-rails-4-with-global-id/) describing how it works.

GlobalID helps you uniquely identify your models. E.g. `gid://Company/1` and `gid://Employee/1` has the same IDs, but different GlobalIDs. You can actually find model simply by using `GlobalID::Locator`:

```
GlobalID::Locator.locate gid_value
```

This should make simple combo-boxes easily programmable.